# how can ı add youtube player video view to a layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, youtube, youtube-api

ı want to add youtube player video view to a layout. and then ı want to add this layout to my context. however ı got an error.

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/yView"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

this is my layout's XML part

and also this is my activity part

```
 var v : View = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.yview, null)
        var y : YouTubePlayerView = v.findViewById(R.id.yView)
```

edit: this is the error "Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView"

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps, it work's for me!

step 1) Add this code in your XML file :

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

step 2) Extend `YouTubeBaseActivity()` with your activity class and your class looks like this:

```
class YoutubePlayerActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    videoId = "VIDEO ID THAT YOU WANT TO PLAY"
    binding.youtubePlayer.initialize("YOUR YOUTUBE API KEY",this)
}

override fun onInitializationSuccess(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubePlayer?, p2: Boolean) {
    if (!p2) {
        p1?.cueVideo(videoId)
    }
}

override fun onInitializationFailure(p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?, p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?) {}
}
```

and it's done!

Comment: My layout has no class so I can't extends anything. On the other hand I extended the activity class that I want to add the layout. However it does not work. But. Thanks for answering.

Comment: in that case, you can use 3rd party library in which you can add a video player and assign a video id while creating a layout. click [here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player)  for reference.

Comment: In the google play console I have seen the error as Your GCP key API was leaked while setting the key in the code